# Word to describe the caring of the seller for the buyer?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, politeness

A buyer and a seller come to a trade agreement. During the discussion, the seller (whose product is good quality) shows that they are a generous person, like so:

- The buyer expresses that although they can handle the original price, a little discount for each product would make the total more affordable. The seller agrees to a discount.
- The buyer requests that due to the time it takes for delivery, the products be sent at once. However, the buyer says that the money can't be sent at once because, even though a discount has been agreed, the sum total is still large. The buyer requests instead that the money be transferred in monthly installments. The seller agrees to both of these requests.
- Eventually however, despite the seller having accepted all the requests of the buyer, it transpires that the buyer has to buy an alternative product from a different seller. The seller understands the situation and kindly allows the buyer to cease the transaction without incurring any costs, penalties or obligations.

Thanks to this generous conduct, the buyer wants to thank the seller. What would be an appropriate term to use in these circumstances?

> Thank you so much for your _______

I know that *kindness*, *caring* or *help* would fit, but I want to find a more specific word or phrase.

Comment: ... or _indulgence_ (old-fashioned).

Comment: @Charon [Accomodate](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=Accommodate&resource=Webster%27s) a good root word pick but I think another variation is more apt to the unadapted example sentence, which would be [Accommodation](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=Accommodation&resource=Webster%27s).

Comment: @Charon is there any difference between *accommodating* and *flexible*?

Comment: I would say that *accommodating* carries more the connotation of meeting another person's specific needs, whereas *flexible* means that there is optionality in the offering but it isn't an adaptation to specific, ad hoc requests from the other party.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The seller has been very *considerate*; he has shown *considerateness* or *consideration*.

> **[considerate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerate)**
>   *adjective* con·sid·er·ate \kən-ˈsi-d(ə-)rət\
>   : thinking about the rights and feelings of other people : showing kindness toward other people  *[m-w.com]*
>
> **[consideration](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consideration)**
>   *noun* con·sid·er·ation \kən-ˌsi-də-ˈrā-shən\
>   : careful thought : the act of thinking carefully about something you will make a decision about
>
> : a desire to avoid doing something that will make another person sad, upset, angry, etc.  *[m-w.com]*

As @talmu pointed out in a comment, it would be more acceptable/idiomatic for the given situation to say something like "Thank you for being so considerate."

Comment: If *considerate* is used, in this case I'd say it's more acceptable to say "Thank you for being so considerate," than "Thank you for your consideration." The latter form is more appropriate when the person giving thanks is being considered by the person being thanked, e.g. for a job position.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct that kindness, caring, and help are the wrong words to use in a business context most of the time.  Businesses are not in business to help the needy, they're there to make money.  Also don't use a word like generosity that might prompt the seller to reconsider whether they're giving up too much in the deal.  I would suggest a word such as *flexibility*.

Comment: what is the difference between *flexibility* and *accommodating*?

Comment: In your sentence above, there would be very little difference, and you could definitely say 'Thank you so much for your accommodations'.  If I had to nitpick though, I'd say flexibility compliments a quality of the seller, whereas accommodations highlights a favor done for the buyer.  You don't want to come across as a charity case in your dealings.

Answer (score 3):

I’d suggest using **understanding** (= a willingness to understand people's behavior and forgive them), either alone or perhaps with the bracketed language below:

> Thank you for your [continuous]
>   [**understanding**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/understanding)
>   [throughout this process].

(Merriam-Webster)

Comment: what is *continuous*?

Comment: @Ooker I was suggesting the possible addition of [continuous](https://www.google.com/search?q=continuous+meaning&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) here to try to convey that the seller's understanding (kindness/consideration/whatever) was present (non-stop, constant, steady) and appreciated throughout/during the entire process, from the negotiation stage of the transaction through its conclusion/termination.

Comment: I see. You should implement this into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Kind-heartedness* would probably fit best.

From what I understand, the seller has already sent all of the items but has not gotten all of the money yet? And instead of asking to send some of the items back, the buyer may keep them? That is a kind-hearted gesture, because the seller is willing to take some financial pain (cost of product) to prevent the buyer from more financial pain (cost of product and/or shipping).

Answer (score 1):

**customer service** (*noun*):

1. the way that an organisation deals with customers, before, during, and after a sale, and the activities involved in dealing with customers

> '*The mobile operator has a reputation for outstanding customer service.*'

Source: [Cambridge Business English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/)

2. the assistance and advice provided by a company to those people who buy or use its products or services

> '*A recent survey on customer service concluded that nine out of ten customers say how they are treated by a business is a major factor in determining where they will buy.*'

Source: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)

Suggested phrasing of OP's sentence:

> '*Thank you so much for your outstanding customer service.*'

Comment: Or just *service*.

Comment: I think that *service* or *customer service* is only used in the company - customer relationship. While this relationship satisfies the customer (*outstanding*), it still doesn't reflect the human - human relationship behinds it. It's *professional*, not *empathy*

Comment: @Ooker Your understanding is incorrect

Comment: Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Ooker here are some links stressing the  importance of empathetic communications with customers, as part of their overall customer service experience: [link 1](http://www.eptica.com/blog/importance-empathy-customer-service-interactions); [link 2](http://www.cmo.com/articles/2013/9/24/understanding_the_ro.html); [link 3](http://corp.yonyx.com/customer-service/importance-empathy-customer-service/), Here is a link from CDO showing that 'customer service' is synonymous with 'customer care': [link 4](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/customer-care)

Comment: @Ooker if you're writing to an employee or manager for an organisation, using a term such as 'customer service' is likely to benefit them more than concentrating solely on their personal qualities. One way round would be to praise their handling of the overall customer experience, and then draw out qualities such as their thoughtfulness and consideration. They may wish to show your letter to management and other contacts, who will be interested in your comments on both the professional and personal aspects of the sales experience.

Comment: ah, I see the problem here. The seller is only one person, not a company

Answer (score 1):

Why not *helpfulness*?

- Example: The level of expertise and helpfulness is higher in small
  shops.
- Definition:  friendliness evidence by a kindly and helpful
  disposition
- Synonyms: cooperation, kindness, support, assistance, sympathy,
  friendliness, rallying round, usefulness, benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for being so ***accommodating***.

Answer (score 1):

It could be *goodwill* on the part of the seller, who hopes the gesture will also reflect on his business’s own goodwill.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "Propriety".  The Owner or Proprietor of
a restaurant, store or service can be said to have an excellent
sense of *propriety* toward his customers.

Example from Websters:
"If Madison felt the same annoyance with the dissenters, his prim sense of political propriety forbade him from stooping to personal attacks. —Jack N. Rakove, Original Meanings … 1996"

Answer (score 0):

I would say the seller has been very [generous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/generous)

> ˈdʒɛn(ə)rəs
>  adjective
>   1. showing a readiness to give more of something, especially money, than is strictly necessary or expected.

(oxforddictionaries.com)

You would thank them for their **[generosity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/generosity)**

> dʒɛnəˈrɒsəti
>  noun 
>   1. the quality of being kind and generous.

(oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Google is not a citable reference.

Comment: @tchrist it demonstrably is

Comment: To the contrary: it absolutely is not. Different people see different things at different times. **“Google” is not a citation.**  The requirement that you have to say where the definition you are quoting is from is not suspended by invoking the name of Google.

Comment: @tchrist The quotation is from Google and they have their own dictionary, which used to be separate and is now integrated into the search. Only if they change the definition will people see a different definition and that's true of all online dictionaries.

Comment: There are directions on our Meta about this issues. So even though I do not concede the point, let us propose that you are actually right despite all that. In that case you have effectively added nothing of your own, reducing ELU to a *Let Me Google That For You* site. That makes this either a non-answer or a very low quality one.

Comment: [This does make for problems when answers simply reproduce the content Google supplies from a `define` query. Presumably Google have an agreement with their sources where they can omit any reference. I don't think we should endorse that, particularly when it's easy to provide cited references from original dictionary websites.](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/6743)

Comment: @tchrist That quote and the answer to that question is one person's opinion, accepted and up-voted six times. That is all.  If there is a policy of "Google is not a citation" then please provide a link to that. It's curious that your answer to that same question was *"If it had been called The Free Dictionary [rather than TFD], this would not have happened."* but the criticism of TFD is the same as for Google: we don't know where they get their definition from (*"I don't think we should endorse that"* in your quote above). So I am confused as to your opinion on this.

Comment: @tchrist And as for *"That makes this either a non-answer or a very low quality one."*  I *would* say the seller has been very generous and that is why I suggest it. That is about the same amount of reasoning that any other answer gives (more than most here in fact).

Comment: The cited Meta posting that says Google is not a citation stands as policy absent a dissenting opinion to the contrary. If you believe the policy to be in error, please post your own answer there and let the community decide on its merits. Meanwhile, this current posting remains at variance with that policy, and so should be improved or deleted.

Comment: @tchrist A footnote in an answer to a different question stands as policy until someone disagrees? For me to disagree with that footnote (of an answer to the question about the use of the Free Dictionary) by giving an answer to that question would be inappropriate (not addressing the question). We should not presume that the OP ticking it and 6 people up-voting did so because they agreed with that one footnote.

Comment: @tchrist I have asked for a definitive position on the topic here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/is-google-dictionary-a-valid-definition-reference-in-particular-in-answers. I would welcome your input on that.